# Legend entries out of box

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

I am using `semilogx` to plot data. Whenever I save the generated graph as an eps or a pdf file, legend entries go out the legend box (see the attachment). However, for .jpg it works fine. Please advise.

Following is the sample code that I use for plot:

```
[fa,xa] = ecdf(Variable_1);
[fb,xb] = ecdf(Variable_2);
set(0,'DefaultLineLineWidth',3)
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName','Helvetica')
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize',18)
set(0,'DefaultTextFontName','Helvetica')
set(0,'DefaultTextFontSize',18)
semilogx(xa,fa,'b--');
hold all
semilogx(xb,fb,'r--');
hold all
legend({'Availability', 'Unavailability'},'location','northwest');
xlabel('Intervals (hours)');
ylabel('Cumulative fraction');
grid off
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not executable. Please provide a [mcve]. I have tried with `Variable_1 = random('wbl',3,1,15,1)` and `Variable_2 = random('wbl',3,1,15,1)` and I get no problem in the pdf file. (R2018a Update 2)

Comment: @SardarUsama Code is working fine. Variable_1 and Variable_2 are the lists. Please generate series of numbers before executing the code.

Comment: I have had some similar problems in the past. One thing you could try is maximizing the figure size on your screen before you save. Give that a try (if you have not yet), and let us know if that worked.

Comment: Use this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first choice would be to get rid of the box:

```
legend({'Availability','Unavailability'},'location','northwest','box','off')
```

If you really want the box, you can manually increase its size, e.g. the increase width by 10%:

```
lposincr = [0 0 .1 0]; % left, bottom, width, height
l = legend({'Availability', 'Unavailability'},'location','northwest');
lpos = get(l,'Position');
set(l,'Position',lpos.*(1+lposincr))
```